# KVM Switch for a mac and a Windows (XP or 7) machine to share VDU

Tags: windows, kvm-switch

Have a MacPro (snow leopard) connected to an (windows standard) Asus 25" monitor via a DVI-->VGA adapter. Now the boss wants me to work from home, so I want to share my Asus display with a Windows XP laptop.  No doubt once my wife sees this, she will want to do the same thing, but with a Windows 7 laptop.

So what I would like, I think, is your recommendations for a KVM switch (or better solution) that allows the Mac and a (windows 7 or windows xp) laptop to share the Asus display.
Bonus marks if they can share Apple keyboard and magic mouse, but am quite happy to use separate mouse keyboards.  The MacPro is the one that is always connected, the laptops come and go.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many kvm switches that work fine with MAC, its not an issue any longer. You can visit kvmstuff.com for viewing the most durable kvm switches and types along with 1 year warranty. or you can search google.
here's the link- http://www.kvmstuff.com/server-management/kvm-switches.html

Comment: thanks for the help - I ended up using a Konig monitor switch from Amazon, at £6 it does the trick. Kinda.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a Video Switch if you are going to use separate keyboards and mice for 2 machines. They type of video switch needed will depend on the video connectors on your machines.